# Creating a legend in Geoserver?

Tags: geoserver

I created a map in Geoserver and I have a lot of layeres.

How can I add a legend to it (hopefully without using code)? I want the user to be able to switch layers on and off.

Comment: GeoServer provides a getlegend request, how to call it depends on the client you are using.

Comment: @iant I am not sure if I completely understand. What is the client? (I am new to all this process).

Comment: a client is the program that makes requests to the server asking for the map etc.